# How many controller files should I create in my Symfony2 application?

Tags: symfony

In the `src/AppBundle/Controller` folder, there is a file called `DefaultController.php`.

I'll create url's like below, should I use just DefaultController.php for all URL requests or is it recommended to use a different controller.php file (UserController.php, FeedController.php, etc) for each part of the site? (profile, feed, settings, etc)

I also have another question. As far as I understand, we put our html files in our `/App/Resources/views` folder to keep them separated. Do I need to create a specific file for each part of the website just like flat PHP? (settings/index.php, settings/password.php, settings/things.php, settings/security.php, etc).

I am not sure whether this question is suitable for SO or not.

settings

```
/settings
/settings/password
/settings/things
/settings/security
/settings/privacy
/settings/ban
/settings/notifications
/settings/mail
/settings/mobile
/settings/applications
/settings/advertising
/settings/invite
```

user

```
/username
/username/photos
/username/friends
/username/posts
```

feed

```
/feed
/feed/posts/postid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both questions is no hard answer. I should create a controller for each part of your website AT LEAST. Theoretical you could throw everything into one controller but it will be a very long list if you are finished. Another problem is that your action names like indexAction will repeat which is of course not possible because every method must have a different name. And names like index1Action, index2Action and so on is also not a proper solution :-). Another helper is to create an own controller for every ENTITY.

Twig files should only be written for one page only or only for a part of a page. Imagine that you have a homepage with last 10 newsitems but also a news page with more news items (maybe with pagination). The newsitems themselves looks the same on both pages. In this case you could make a home.html.twig, a news.html.twig and also a newsitem.html.twig. Both home and news will include newsitem to show the newsitems...

Hope i gave you a light.

Comment: Yes, you did. Thank you.